# Missing Interface on Service stack

Tags: servicestack

I wasnt sure where to post this but I have just downloaded the latest SRC from service stack.

**I can see that this project file:**
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.csproj
**References:**

```
<Compile Include="Auth\IAuthRepository.cs" />
```

But when I go here:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth
There is no IAuthRepository.

Hence my build of service stack wont compile.

Thanks
RuSs

Comment: You shouldn't use **master** which has been [heavily refactored and under heavy development](https://plus.google.com/106787359118990653189/posts/P3ruPpFZezp). Instead you can build from the [v3 branch](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/v3). I'll look at redeploying to NuGet tomorrow morning.

Comment: Thanks @mythz I am still new to how to use github correctly

Comment: np :) Also just pushed a new NuGet today, so it should now be in-sync with the v3 branch.